# Is there a way to control the moving of custom icons on zoom in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, anchor, markers

We have a requirement of plotting a store marker and along with it custom marker with store marker making it one icon. We get 'svg' as concatenated text and rendering them. Though they are rendered properly, we are unable to center the icon to the given lat long point. On zoom/pan, icon is moving away from the bound lat long.

We have difficulty using div icon and faced few issues. Hence we are using 'bindTooltip' for rendering the composite icon.

Please look at the sample code below:

```
var iconText = '"<div><span style="font-size: 10px; color: #000000;">7-ELEVEN #32544<span><br/><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"><g stroke-width="1"><path d="M10,1 C6.69166271,1 4,3.69166797 4,7.00001172 C4,7.99317578 4.24830811,8.97790234 4.72035016,9.85132422 L9.67188736,18.8066406 C9.7378052,18.9260313 9.86341824,19 10,19 C10.1365818,19 10.2621948,18.9260313 10.3281126,18.8066406 L15.281478,9.84837109 C15.7516919,8.97790234 16,7.99314062 16,6.99997656 C16,3.69166797 13.3083373,1 10,1 Z M10,10 C8.34583136,10 7.00001758,8.65418359 7.00001758,7.00001172 C7.00001758,5.34583984 8.34583136,4.00002344 10,4.00002344 C11.6541686,4.00002344 12.9999824,5.34583984 12.9999824,7.00001172 C12.9999824,8.65418359 11.6541686,10 10,10 Z" fill="#000000"/></g></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="label-class" width="200.75693543198784" height="11.756935431987843"><rect width="10.756935431987843" height="10.756935431987843" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" x="0" y="0"/><g><circle cx="5.378467715993921" cy="5.378467715993923" r="3.227080629596353" fill="#0099ff" stroke="#0099ff" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1"/><text font-size="10" font-weight="" font-style="" text-decoration="" fill="#000000" x="10.756935431987841" y="-3.137439500996452"><tspan x="10.756935431987841" dy="10.756935431987843">Convenience_Aug 2017: $5.12K</tspan></text></g></svg></div>"';

//myIcon1 is icon with iconSize and iconUrl and iconAnchor properties set.
//iconText above is same as iconUrl in myIcon1
const marker = L.marker([44.1016,-69.3809],{icon: myIcon1});
marker.addTo(map);  
marker.bindTooltip(iconText, { direction: 'left', permanent: true});
```

I expect the icon to be anchored to the given lat long. It should not move away from the location.

Comment: How are you creating `myIcon1`? How does it look like? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310615/leaflet-icon-marker-does-not-appear-in-the-right-point-of-the-map or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341274/leaflet-js-api-icons-why-do-iconanchor-and-popupanchor-have-different-coordinat